# IFS=: "set $var" versus "set toto:fofo"

Tags: bash

This is probably a stupid question but i am trying to understand why version 1 of the code below works and version 2 doesn't:

version 1:

```
$ VAR=toto:fofo:bar
$ IFS=:
$ set $VAR
$ echo $1
toto
```

version 2:

```
$ IFS=:
$ set toto:fofo:bar
$ echo $1
toto fofo bar
```

I don't understand why in the first version ':' are interpreted as a separator but in the second one they are not interpreted at all as if they are only interpreted if they are the output of a variable substitution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. Word splitting only applies to the result of unquoted parameter expansions and command substitutions. It does not affect shell parsing or grammar.

Here's `man bash` with emphasis:

> `IFS`
>
> The  Internal  Field Separator that is used for word splitting *after expansion* [...]